# MySQL Get One Column Only Once

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have 2 MySQL tables in which I get data from in one query

"tables" table:
[image]

"checks" table:
[image]

The query I have been trying and the result of it:

```
SELECT tables.tableName, tables.tableRes, tables.tableResFor, checks.chkID, checks.chkDate, checks.chkStatus 
FROM tables 
LEFT JOIN checks ON tables.tableID=checks.chkTable 
WHERE tables.tableID=3 
ORDER BY checks.chkStatus DESC, checks.chkID ASC
```

[image]

Here are the problems

- If there were no results from the query, I need the tableName column which comes out never null, so other columns can be null (works now)
- I don't want to get the rows after first row, if the chkStatus column is 1 or 0 or null, shortly I need the rows with 2 on chkStatus, if the first row is 0, 1 or null, I don't need the other rows...

Thanks in advance, I have been working on this problem for more than 10 hours...

Comment: Can't you just add `AND checks.chkStatus = 2` to the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: The second bullet of the problem is confusing for me. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I need the other checks where chkStatus is 2*  **so, add the condition to the join**

```
    SELECT
        tables.tableName
      , tables.tableRes
      , tables.tableResFor
      , checks.chkID
      , checks.chkDate
      , checks.chkStatus
    FROM tables
    LEFT JOIN checks ON tables.tableID = checks.chkTable AND chkStatus = 2
    WHERE tables.tableID = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need the other checks where chkStatus is 2, they might be more than one

Comment: I revised my answer following your comment `(by the way "I don't want to get the rows after first row" is why I used the prior approach)`

Comment: Thanks! Adding that condition to the join (which is what I didn't know anything about) worked well. (There, I meant if the chkStatus was 1 or 0  or null, but it works tho)